# LU is not same as A when I used torch.solver

Tags: pytorch, linear-algebra

let `A=[[3,2],[1,-3]]` and `B=[[3],[-10]]`
and solve equation `AX=B` by using `torch.solve`:

```py
X, LU = torch.solve(B,A)
```

Then I got `X=[[-1],[3]]` and `LU=[[3,2],[0.333,-3.666]]`.

According to definition of LU decompose, `LU` must be same as `A`, however they aren't same.

Can anyone explain this???

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The representation you got is a compact way of representing the lower trainagular matrix `L` and the upper trainagular matrix `U`. You can use [`torch.tril`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tril.html#torch.tril) and [`torch.triu`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tril.html#torch.triu) to get these matrices explicitly:

```py
L = torch.tril(LU, -1) + torch.eye(LU.shape[-1])
U = torch.triu(LU)
```

verify:

> ```
> In [*]: L
> Out[*]:
> tensor([[1.0000, 0.0000],
>        [0.3333, 1.0000]])
> ```

> ```
> In [*]: U
> Out[*]:
> tensor([[ 3.0000,  2.0000],
>         [ 0.0000, -3.6667]])
> ```

And the product is indeed equal to `A`:

> ```
> In [*]: torch.dist(L @ U , A)
> Out[*]: tensor(0.)
> ```